# How many times does this function operate?

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

```c
int fun_3(int a[], int n){
    int sum = 0;
    for (i=0 ; i<n ;i++){
        for (j=0 ; j<n ; j++){
            for (k=0 ; k<n ; k++){
                if (a[i] > 100)
                    sum += 1;
   return sum;
}
```

I counted the number of operations in the worst case of this code divided by addition operation, comparison operation, and assignment operation(The operation time is not taken into account).

**assignment operation:**

int sum = 0 -> 1 operation

for (i=0;;) -> 1 operation

for (;;i++) -> n operation

for (j=0;;) -> n operation

for (;;j++) -> n^2 operation

for (k=0;;) -> n^2 operation

for (;;k++) -> n^3 operation

sum += 1 -> n^3 operation

total operations in assignment = 2n^3 + 2n^2 + 2n + 2

**addition operation:**

for(;;i++) -> n operation

for(;;j++) -> n^2 operation

for(;;k++) -> n^3 operation

sum += 1 -> n^3 operation

total operations in addition = 2n^3 + n^2 + n

**comparison operation:**

for(;i<n;) -> n+1

for(;j<n;) -> n(n+1) -> n^2+n

for(;k<n;) -> n^2(n+1) -> n^3+n^2

if (a[i] > 100) -> n^3

total operations in comparison = 2n^3 + 2n^2 + 2n + 1

**Total number of operations for this code = 6n^3 + 5n^2 + 5n + 3**

But my university colleagues' result and my result are different each other. I wonder if what I calculated was right or wrong.

Comment: Were the cost of all such operation specified in the question or you have made an assumption?

Comment: I think it is O(n^3)

Comment: What matters is the [`Big O`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)... Your code is `O(n^3)`, ie: doubling the number of elements makes it perform `8` (2^3) times worse.

Answer (score 0):

You should just assume the bigger exponent and not the constants. You should know how to report the time complexities of codes in computer science. Read about the Big O notation [Here-Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#:%7E:text=Big%20O%20notation%20is%20a,a%20particular%20value%20or%20infinity.&text=Big%20O%20notation%20characterizes%20functions,using%20the%20same%20O%20notation.) or [Here-GFGlink](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-algorithms-big-o-analysis/)
First of all you should allocate `i, j, k`.

Now you have something like it:

```
int fun_3(int a[], int n){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0 ; i<n ;i++) {
        for (int j=0 ; j<n ; j++) {
            for (int k=0 ; k<n ; k++) {
                if (a[i] > 100)
                    sum += 1;
   return sum;
}
```

In the worst case this code operate O(n<sup>3</sup>) operations.